# Php - print html tags as text

Tags: php, html, tags

I need to print an HTML tag on screen as texts (and not in code).

I need the readers to literally read the tag.

What is the best practice to do so ?

```
print htmlspecialchars('<meta name="copyright" content="© Winston Smith, 1984">');
```

or

```
print htmlentities('<meta name="copyright" content="© Winston Smith, 1984">');
```

or none of the above.

- Is there a better way?
- What else should I consider ?
- And last question - should I use print, echo or is there no
  difference ?

****EDIT I****

I already seen a problem with the character "©" with htmlentities().
This only confirms my doubts - which one is safe to use for all cases - and is there another way to print html tags as text ?

Comment: thanks for the input -  the problem is not the copyright symbol per se. the problem is to print the tags as readable text on screen , and not in code. the sub-problem is to make it safe for all characters such as Ä Ü ü ß ° etc. etc . even if i do not know what they will be ..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically all you really need to make HTML readable as text is:

```
$out = strtr($input,Array("<"=>"&lt;","&"=>"&amp;"));
```

`htmlspecialchars` is basically a subset of `htmlentities`. `htmlentities` encodes EVERYTHING that has an entity alternative, namely all the named entities and a handful of codes.

Comment: thanks! - that works for now !  but will that work on all content (I do not know which characters will be inside , I only know the tags need to be on screen and not in the code) . also, just because i want to understand more - if htmlspecialchars isa subset of htmlentities - why is htmlentities producing "Â©" and htmlspecialchars produces "©"

Comment: I think your issue has something to do with the encoding used on the characters. I had the same issue but I can't remember how or even if I fixed it.